# MacOS: xargs cp does not copy subdirectories

Tags: wordpress, macos, bash

I am on Mac OS.

I have a directory with round about 3000 files and several subdirectories (wordpress installation)

Now I have to find all the files in a similar directory (have to separate master and child installation) that are additional files and have to copy them away into another directory.

I use this command:

```
$ diff -rq dt-the7 dt-the7-master-from-Yana|grep 'Only in dt-the7'|awk {' print $3 $4 '}|sed 's/:/\//g'|xargs -J {} rsync -av {} neu/
```

but somehow a certain file 3d.png and a list of other that should be in a subdir of the destination dir are copied into the root dir of the destination.

Any idea why that might be?

It makes no difference whether I use cp, rsync or ditto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `-R` relative option on your `rsync` command.

Without this `rsync` just copies the item referenced rather than the path referenced, so items at the root level are copied as you expected but items in sub-directories are also copied to the root, which is not what you wanted.

With the option `rsync` takes account of the relative path and recreates it at the destination.

An example with another command might help, consider:

```
cp A/B.txt C/
```

that will copy `B.txt` into `C`, it does *not* create a folder `A` in `C` which in turn contains the file `B.txt`. `rsync` without `-R` behaves like that `cp` command, with `-R` it creates the `A` directory in `C`.

HTH